# Using ews-javascript-api but not sure how to query with localtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, exchangewebservices

I am using ews-javascript-api and when I make a call to CalendarView the startTime and endTime are in UTC.

How do I change the timeZone to 'Central Standard Time' when making the call?

Comment: The last post in this discussion may be of use to you [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/8409effc-9ccd-4db0-b42b-55b9b0e0fb3a/ews-java-specify-the-time-zone-when-instantiate-the-exchangeservice-object-or-replyforward-the?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not yet complete. track here https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api/issues/148

[disclaimer - I am the author of the library]

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was going crazy ;)

Comment: this issue is now closed, check version 0.9+ on npm